# Enum value conversion

Tags: c#, casting, enums

What is the goal of explicitly casting an enum to it's declared type in, for example,

```
enum MyEnum : long 
{
   Zero,
   One,
};

long one = (long)MyEnum.Zero; // <-- explicit conversion
```

Is there a logical explanation for this?

Comment: Are you asking why would you want to cast an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying type of enum (`long` in your case) specifies only how much storage is allocated for each enumerator. The type of enum itself is `System.Enum` so you need explicit cast.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few reasons but the main one that I use it for is when saving the field to a DB. The column in the DB has a data type that is `int` (in my case) and I use the conversion to allow me to save the enum value in the table.

Comment: Ok but why type  specified  in declaration is not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

That declaration tells compiler that you will use large values, but enum is still enum and it will not implicitly convert to any type. It's to be sure you know what you're doing, I think.

From C# Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/sbbt4032.aspx

> In the following example, the base-type option is used to declare an enum whose members are of type long. Notice that even though the underlying type of the enumeration is long, the enumeration members still must be explicitly converted to type long by using a cast.